# Are switching engine questions okay?

Tags: discussion

I'm considering switching my game over to a different engine. Would it be an acceptable question to explain what I'm going for, what I'm using, why I'm switching, and ask what engine would best suit my needs?

Answer (score 3):

My guess us that it would come across as a "which tech should I use" question and get closed.